PyQt5 SetWindowIcon from SVG from qrc resources rendered blurry/pixelized/wrong?
Consider this example:
File logo.svg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg201"
   x="0"
   y="0"
   style="enable-background:new 0 0 773.3 769"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 773.3 769"
   sodipodi:docname="logo.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.2.1 (9c6d41e410, 2022-07-14)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs
   id="defs31" /><sodipodi:namedview
   id="namedview29"
   pagecolor="#ffffff"
   bordercolor="#666666"
   borderopacity="1.0"
   inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
   inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
   inkscape:pagecheckerboard="1"
   inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
   showgrid="false"
   inkscape:zoom="0.53105125"
   inkscape:cx="409.56499"
   inkscape:cy="440.63544"
   inkscape:window-width="1280"
   inkscape:window-height="657"
   inkscape:window-x="-8"
   inkscape:window-y="-8"
   inkscape:window-maximized="1"
   inkscape:current-layer="g574" />
  <style
   id="style2"
   type="text/css">.st2,.st4 { stroke:#231f20;stroke-miterlimit:10 }
.st2 { fill:none;stroke-width:20 }
.st4 { stroke-width:10 }
.st4,.st66 { fill:#fff }
</style>
  <g
   id="g574"><g
     id="targetgrp"><circle
       id="XMLID_431_"
       cx="386.7"
       cy="382.3"
       r="302.6"
       class="st2"
       style="stroke:#000000" /><path
       id="XMLID_432_"
       style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10;stroke-miterlimit:10;fill:none"
       d="M 185.55313 382.3 L 39.6 382.3 " /><path
       id="path431"
       class="st4"
       d="M 737.3 382.3 L 587.84755 382.29999 "
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000" /></g></g>
</svg>

It looks like this in Inkscape:

Then I refer this logo.svg in file resources.qrc:
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
  <file alias="logo.svg">logo.svg</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>

... and I "compile" the resources.qrc into qrc_resources.py with:
pyrcc5 -o qrc_resources.py resources.qrc

Then I have this as test_pyqt5.py file:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os

os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"]   = "1"
os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
os.environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"]             = "1"

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# remember `pyrcc5 -o qrc_resources.py resources.qrc`
import qrc_resources

class My_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(My_MainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle('Testing PyQt5')
    self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':logo.svg'))
    self.show()

def main(args):
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps) # https://stackoverflow.com/q/58430006
  wind = My_MainWindow()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv[1:])

When I run python3 test_pyqt5.py, I get this:

Note that the application window is barely visible - seemingly just the left line is rendered; same for app icon Windows toolbar (tricky to see, as its black, but possible if the toolbar element is selected):

... and same with app icon in Alt-Tab switcher:

What's going on here, and how can I get the SVG icon for the application rendered fully?
Versions:
$ uname -s
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045

$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.8

$ pacman -Q mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5
mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5 5.15.10-2


This doesn't seem related to Qt, but to how the SVG is defined. Both the circle and the right line only define the stroke color, but not the width. Try to explicitly set the stroke width of both, and it should be shown correctly.

Thanks @musicamante - that was it; weird that Inkscape did show for instance stroke width 20 for the circle, and 10 for the lines - even without stroke-width:10; in the SVG XML!? But then, those were stored in .st2 CSS styles in the SVG, so it seems, the actual problem is that PyQt5 does not really support CSS styles in SVG? Anyways, just did a + then - in Fill and Stroke / Stroke Style / Width in Inkscape - the attribute got added, and rendering is more correct now

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075008/6197439 on how to remove CSS class styles and "bake" the corresponding attributes "in" the elements themselves in Inkscape

Qt5 supports the SVG 1.2 Tiny specification only, and I'm not sure that includes "standard" styling as the base implementation does.
